# Expandable panel with layering

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, jlayeredpane

I've trying to get two `JPanel`s to layer on top of one another, but at the same time, expand to fit the size of their parent. For example, if the `JFrame` that contains the two layered `JPanel`s is expanded, the layered `JPanel`s also expand to fill the entire `JFrame`, and vice-versa when the `JFrame` is collapsed.

The idea is to create a top layer that contains buttons and other Swing components that control a bottom layer, but the bottom layer can still be seen through the top layer (by setting the top layer's properties to `setOpaque(false)`). At the same time, both the top and the bottom layers should fill the available size of their container (the `JPanel` or `JFrame` that contains the layers).

I have already tried working with `JLayeredPane`, but the size of the pane must be known in advanced (as far I have been able to get it working so far). These size constraints will change as the size of the containing `JPanel` or `JFrame` change.

Thank you in advanced for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### You Could...

Try using a [`OverlayLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/OverlayLayout.html), but I'm not sure it will meet your requirements.

### You Could

Set use a `GridBagLayout` on the `JLayeredPane`, placing each component at the same `gridx`/`gridy` and then filling with `GridBagConstraints.BOTH` and a `weightx`/`weighty` of `1`

### You Could

Use the frame's "glass pane" as the top layer.  Which will allow you to place controls over the top the frame's "content pane"

See [How to use root panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) for more details.

Comment: Your second "You could" got it to work, in combination with http://stackoverflow.com/a/11197851/2403253. It's important to use `setLayer(...)` prior to adding the components (as shown in the question I linked to). Thank you very much. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @unseenghost Personally, I like the third one, less hassle from POV, but what ever works ;)